# Excel Rule: Mark both cells (but only them!) in yellow when their difference is greater than 14. Tried my formula but not working

Tags: excel, formula, rules

I have 2 rows with dates and I want to mark both dates if the difference between them is greater than 14 days.

Example:

```
 D           E
```

14.03.2018  15.03.2018

14.03.2018  21.04.2018

14.03.2018  28.03.2018

14.03.2018  21.03.2018

Formula: = (E1-D1)>14
Format: infill yellow. 
Applying it to the whole ROW E.

Problem is, that when its True then the whole row gets turned yellow, not the Cell in E.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have applied the conditional formatting in one cell and then copied format in entire column. Please select the entire column first then apply the formatting as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

I am getting following[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` change `Applies to` into:

```
=$E:$E
```